# Jquery animation loop multiple time

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a loop issue with this code :

```
<p style="position:relative;left:100px;opacity:0" class="bc1">hello</p>
```

I want to loop the animation three loop with jquery to:

1. `$('.bc1').animate({left: '0px',opacity:'1'},1000);`
2. delay 10 second
3. `$('.bc1').animate({left: '100px',opacity:'0'},1000);`
4. delay 1 second
5. then start again from 1

and can I make it infinite?

I tried:

```
var st=animateBac();
        var af=animateRev();
        st();           
        af();
```

but it's not looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var animationIsOn = true;
var anim;
anim = function(){
    $('.bc1').animate({left: '0px',opacity:'1'},1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.bc1').animate({left: '100px',opacity:'0'},1000);
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(animationIsOn){
                anim();
            }
        },1000);
    },10000);
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, didn't add the delays.

Comment: it works fine but what if i want to loop it for 3 loops only??

Comment: Add a counter, like instead of animationIsOn = animationLoops = 0, and in the inner if ou put "if(animationLoops < 3){ animationLoops += 1; anim(); }"